# Is it possible to get phonegap functionality on a mobile website just by embedding the js file?

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an existing mobile web site on which I would like my users to upload pictures. Since it is not possible in the mobile's web Browser, I would like to know if I could just take the JS file and call the javascript's functions to get the picture taken by the camera for example.
Thanks for your help,
Julien

Comment: Since this question has been asked a couple things have happened regarding accessing the camera and photos on a mobile device. There's the `type="file"` input that is supported in iOS as well as the `getUserMedia` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently only Native applications can access device-specific functionality, like access to the photos gallery...

Answer (score 0):

No. Accessing the camera requires using native APIs, and thus a native wrapper for your website. The phonegap js file talks to the native wrapper to be able to access those features.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how this will pan out, but:

"In addition, mobile Firefox supports the latest web technologies like HTML5, CSS, offline storage, and JavaScript, including Javascript access to device capabilities like geolocation, camera, and calling."

Taken from this [article](http://www.geek.com/articles/mobile/mozilla-launches-awesome-mobile-firefox-on-maemo-as-the-first-mobile-browser-with-add-ons-2010021/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting an  and the most new mobile devices would open a dialog and choose of relative apps install on the device from which you can upload files, thus including camera and gallery.